# merging Large csv files

Tags: r, csv

I have several csv files, and each file has around 50,000 rows. All the files have columns named `id` and `PositionX`. I want to cbind  them only if id and PositionX are the same. If not same just put an NA. I am using following:

```
datlist<-list(Cfour,Cfive,Csix,Cseven,Cten,Ctwelve,Cthirteen,Cfourteen,Cfifteen,Csixteen,Cseventeen,Cnineteen,Ctwoone,Ctwofour,Ctwosix,Ctwonine,Cthreethree,Cthreeseven,Cfourty)
ss<-Reduce(function(df1,df2) merge(df1,df2,by=c("id", "PositionX"),all=T),datlist)
```

For example file 1 have,

```
id PositionX val1
1 5 4.2
2 8 4.3
```

and file 2 has

```
  id PositionX val2
    1 5 6.3
    2 8 9.3
```

and file 3 has

```
  id PositionX val3
        0 5 6.2
        2 8 9.3
```

I want to have

```
     id PositionX val1 val2 val3
      0 5  NA NA 6.2
      1 5  4.2 6.3 NA
  ...
```

Is there a way to do this quickly?

Comment: have you checked `full_join` from `dplyr` package?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. You want to combine multiple CSV files (data frames), which have id, positionX, and other data. What other data? What if more than two csv files have the same id, positionX variables? How many variables will be in the output data? Are you just trying to convert from a long to a wide format? Show some example inputs and outputs.

Comment: @Spacedman I hope this is clear.

Comment: @Jamil yes! much clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`full_join` from the `dlpyr` package is a bit faster than `merge`. Reproducible example follows:

```
> set.seed(123)
> library(dplyr)
> d = data.frame(id=1:100,Pos=1:100,val1=runif(100))
> f1 = d[sample(100,80),]
> f2 = d[sample(100,80),]
> f3 = d[sample(100,80),]
> names(f2)[3]="val2"
> names(f3)[3]="val3"
> head(f1)
   id Pos      val1
60 60  60 0.3744628
33 33  33 0.6907053
48 48  48 0.4659625
93 93  93 0.3435165
47 47  47 0.2330341
85 85  85 0.1028646
> head(f2)
   id Pos      val2
84 84  84 0.7881958
31 31  31 0.9630242
70 70  70 0.4398317
26 26  26 0.7085305
58 58  58 0.7533079
```

and similarly for `f3`.

To do the merge using `dplyr`, its:

```
> jd = Reduce(full_join, list(f1,f2,f3))
Joining, by = c("id", "Pos")
Joining, by = c("id", "Pos")
```

Giving:

```
> head(jd %>% arrange(id))
  id Pos      val1      val2      val3
1  1   1 0.2875775        NA 0.2875775
2  2   2        NA        NA 0.7883051
3  3   3        NA 0.4089769 0.4089769
4  4   4        NA 0.8830174 0.8830174
5  5   5 0.9404673 0.9404673 0.9404673
6  6   6 0.0455565        NA 0.0455565
```

Which is the same as your:

```
> head(Reduce(function(df1,df2) merge(df1,df2,by=c("id", "Pos"),all=T),list(f1,f2,f3)))
  id Pos      val1      val2      val3
1  1   1 0.2875775        NA 0.2875775
2  2   2        NA        NA 0.7883051
3  3   3        NA 0.4089769 0.4089769
4  4   4        NA 0.8830174 0.8830174
5  5   5 0.9404673 0.9404673 0.9404673
6  6   6 0.0455565        NA 0.0455565
```

Except not sorted by `id` (hence the `arrange`).

To benchmark, first we need a `full_join` wrapper function that specifies the columns so that when we benchmark it it doesn't spend all its time screaming messages:

```
> fj = function(a,b){full_join(a,b,by=c("id","Pos"))}
```

And now we can run the benchmark after using `library(microbenchmark)`:

```
> microbenchmark(Reduce(fj,list(f1,f2,f3)),Reduce(function(df1,df2) merge(df1,df2,by=c("id", "Pos"),all=T),list(f1,f2,f3)))
Unit: microseconds
                                                                                            expr
                                                                    Reduce(fj, list(f1, f2, f3))
 Reduce(function(df1, df2) merge(df1, df2, by = c("id", "Pos"),      all = T), list(f1, f2, f3))
      min       lq     mean    median       uq       max neval
  860.491  901.746 1108.901  936.0205 1016.623  6951.609   100
 3133.837 3245.754 4092.630 3291.7825 3616.122 15828.191   100
```

Your actual speedup (or slowdown) may depend on how sparse your matches are, how many rows, columns, data frames etc.

Answer (score 1):

not sure about SQL's capability to handle that big file, but a join with if-then-when command could help - if you go with using SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

use data.table package to do it faster (may work)

```
library(data.table)
df1=data.table(df1)
df2=data.table(df2)
df3=data.table(df3)

setkey(df1, id, PositionX)
setkey(df2, id, PositionX)
setkey(df2, id, PositionX)

j1=df1[df2, alpha := i.alpha]
j2=df3[j1, alpha := i.alpha]
```

In base R this definitely works

```
> df1
  id PositionX val1
1  1         5  4.2
2  2         8  4.3
> df2
  id PositionX val2
1  1         5  6.3
2  2         8  9.3
> df3
  id PositionX val3
1  0         5  6.2
2  2         8  9.3
> merge(df1,df2,by=c("id","PositionX"))
  id PositionX val1 val2
1  1         5  4.2  6.3
2  2         8  4.3  9.3
> j1=merge(df1,df2,by=c("id","PositionX"))
> j1
  id PositionX val1 val2
1  1         5  4.2  6.3
2  2         8  4.3  9.3
> merge(j1,df3,by=c("id","PositionX"))
  id PositionX val1 val2 val3
1  2         8  4.3  9.3  9.3
> merge(j1,df3,by=c("id","PositionX"),all=T)
  id PositionX val1 val2 val3
1  0         5   NA   NA  6.2
2  1         5  4.2  6.3   NA
3  2         8  4.3  9.3  9.3
```

dplyr would work faster on data.table formats
 http://stat545.com/bit001_dplyr-cheatsheet.html#full_joinsuperheroes-publishers

Comment: Please read the updated question, and don't jump in on unclear questions.

Comment: Aye Aye Captain!